# Stray punctuation in references with model3-num-names.bst of elsarticle

Tags: bibtex, elsarticle

I am using the `model3-num-names.bst` to format my citations and references. In some of the references, particularly the ones missing page numbers, I see extra semicolons and commas at the end of the entries. I am guessing this is happening because `model3-num-names.bst` has not been set up to handle missing page numbers.

[image]

This is the minimal `.tex` to reproduce the issue:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{numcompress}
\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}
\begin{document}
Citations that are not correct: \cite{Weber2018}, \cite{Miller2015}

Citations that are correct: \cite{Tomlinson2018b}, \cite{Corrigan2016}

\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

And this is the associated `mybibfile.bib`:

```
@techreport{Corrigan2016,
    author={Corrigan, Steve},
    title={Introduction to the Controller Area Network ({CAN})},
    institution={Texas Instruments},
    year={2016},
    type={Application Report}
}

@inproceedings{Weber2018,
    author  = {Marc Weber and Simon Klug and Eric Sax and Bastian Zimmer},
    title   = {Embedded Hybrid Anomaly Detection for Automotive {CAN} Communication},
    booktitle   ={9th European Congress on Embedded Real Time Software and Systems (ERTS 2018)},
    year    = {2018},
    month   = {jan}
}

@article{Miller2015,
    title={Remote Exploitation of an Unaltered Passenger Vehicle},
    author={Miller, Charlie and Valasek, Chris},
    journal={Black Hat USA},
    year={2015}
}

@inproceedings{Tomlinson2018b,
    title = "Using A One-Class Compound Classifier To Detect In-Vehicle Network Attacks",
    author = "Tomlinson, {Andrew John} and Jeremy Bryans and Siraj Shaikh",
    year = "2018",
    month = jul,
    day = "6",
    doi = "10.1145/3205651.3208223",
    language = "English",
    isbn = "978-1-4503-5764-7",
    pages = "1926--1929",
    booktitle = "Proceedings of the Genetic and Evolutionary Computation Conference Companion",
    publisher = "Association for Computing Machinery",
    address = "United States",
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1145/3205651.3208223}
}
```

I am relatively new to LaTeX and I do not really know how to edit `model3-num-names.bst` to fix this issue. I would be grateful for any advice or hack!